# Rename file and change content windows batch

Tags: windows, batch-file, rename

My problem seems to be simple but I did not find something efficient on the web so far.

I have a list of file, somethig like

```
file0011.xml
doc0011.xml
toto0011.xml
```

containing some occurences of `0011` in their body.
I would like to, in the meantime:
- Replace the 0011 by anything I want, like 0012
- Replace all the occurences of 0011 by 0012 in all the files.

So, the command line would look like `mayBatch.bat 0011 0012`.

I have found something to replace some text parts in multiple files but only "for the display".
So I think I need to
- Parse the files contained in a folder to get their name
- Replace the occurences of the first argument with the one of the second in their name (ren function?)
- Replace the occurences contained in the files of the first argument by the second.

My issue: I do not have any idea of how to do it in a windows batch... Could you help me?

Thanks !

Comment: Are all the files in a single folder?

Comment: Yes they are, in the one of the batch file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "line=%2"
IF NOT DEFINED line ECHO syntax %0 from to&GOTO :eof
SET "sourcedir=c:\sourcedir"
FOR /f "tokens=1*delims=" %%a IN ('dir /b /a-d "%sourcedir%\*%1.xml" ') DO (
 CALL :process %%1 %%2 "%%a"
)

GOTO :EOF

:process
SET "file=%~3"
CALL SET "file=%%file:%1=%2%%"
(
FOR /f "usebackqdelims=" %%x IN ("%sourcedir%\%~3") DO (
 SET "line=%%x"
 SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
 SET "line=!line:%~1=%~2!"
 ECHO(!line!
 endlocal
)
)>"%sourcedir%\%file%"

GOTO :eof
```

You's need to set your source directory into the obvious place. This unceremoniously overwites the destination filename if it exists, so a new file is created with the new name and changed contents. The original file is retained, bt adding

```
del "%sourcedir%\%~3"
```

just before the `goto :eof` in the `:process` routine should finish that off.

(after testing and verification, naturally)

Answer (score 0):

Test this on some sample files.

`myBatch.bat 0011 0012.`

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir *.xml /b /a-d') do (
   set "name=%%~nxa"
   ren "%%a" "!name:%1=%2!"
)
```